# jQuery.sheet: Cross-sheet calculations

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

How do I do cross-sheet calculations in jQuery.sheet. The home page http://visop-dev.com/Project+jQuery.sheet says it supports but I've so far not been able to see any example like that.

By cross-sheet calculations, I want to be able to for example execute Sum on data in sheet1 from sheet 2.

I tried `sheet1:A2:A10` but with no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found the answer. It was right before me the whole time. To access a cell or cell range in another sheet, use the expression like:

```
SHEET1!A4
SHEET1!A2:A10
```

The important thing to notes are

- Cell names are case insenstive
- Sheets cannot be referenced by name but by numbers with the first one being 1
- The word sheet in SHEET1, for example, must be all caps.

Just got that from the jison file
http://jquerysheet.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/parser/parser.jison